# Programmatic way to restore deleted emails from a mailbox audit report in Office365 exchange online?

Tags: email, office365, exchange

I have a user with "relaxed" inbox management practices. They accidentally deleted their entire inbox at once, thousands of emails. As far as I can tell, they are in the deleted items box, but that box has about 30k emails in it.

I generated an audit report. Also an ediscovery capture as a fallback.

What I am looking for is a programmatic way to restore all the items that were deleted in that one fell swoop. Otherwise we'll be spending countless hours manually sifting through all those thousands of emails.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of Outlook desktop client, we could show the modified time of Items in the Deleted items folder via View > View Settings > Columns like below.
[image]

So, you could choose which items to recover based on the modified time.